# cant get jQuery plugin - timepicker - to work within jsp page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsp

Hey guys so I cant get a jquery plugin to work - timepicker - I have a datepicker already set up and working.  I have researched this for many hours, I have tried different plugins.  Procedure that I am doing....downloading the plugin, importing .js file to my projects resources/js folder (I am using spring by the way), I then copy the .css file (of the timepicker) to the resources/css folder.  I then add a script below the script that imports the standard jquery library to import the plugin...below you can see how I implemented it.  Thank you for the help.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>Home</title>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='<c:url value="/resources/css/styles.css" />' />
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='<c:url value="/resources/css/jquery- ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css" />' />
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='<c:url value="/resources/css/jquery.timepicker.css" />' />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='<c:url value="/resources/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js" />'></script>
<script src='<c:url value="/resources/js/jquery.timepicker.min.js" />'></script>
<script>
$(function() {
  $("#dateStart").datepicker();
  $("#dateEnd").datepicker();
});
</script>
<script>
$(function() {
 $('.timeStart').timepicker();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='header-container'>
<div id='header-content'>
    <a href='<c:url value="/" />'>414Cal</a>
    <div id='header-content-right'>
        <a href='<c:url value="/signout" />'>Sign Out, ${ user.email }</a>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div id='body-content'>
<h1>
    414Cal Event Creator
</h1>
<c:if test="${!empty username}">
    ${username = "User"}
</c:if>
<h3>
    ${username}
</h3>
<form action='<c:url value="/createEvent" />' method='post'>
    <p><input type='text' name='eventTitle' size='58' placeholder='Title' /></p>
    <p><input type='text' name='eventLocation' size='58' placeholder='Location' /></p>
    <p><textarea name='eventDescription' rows='5' cols='42'     placeholder='Description'></textarea></p>
    <p>Start<input type='text' name='dateStart' id='dateStart' /> <input type='text'  name='.timeStart' id='.timeStart' /> to <input type='text' name='dateEnd' id='dateEnd' /></p>
    <p><input type='checkbox' name='allDay'> All day</p>
    <p><input type='checkbox' name='repeat' id='repeat'> Repeat</p> 
    <p><input type='submit' /></p> 
</form>

}

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The HTML elements that you're initializing datepicker on do not appear in your JSP file.

Comment: I think I didn't word my question right, datepicker is working fine, it is timepicker that is not working, also there is a line that is incorrect it should be

Comment: $("#timeStart").timepicker();  are you saying that I need to first initialize the HTML elements? thank you

Comment: @user3020017 Oh okay, sorry :-) I think I see the problem. Your selector is looking for an element with an ID of 'timestart'. However, the ID of your element is '.timestart'. If you remove the dot from the ID it should work.

Comment: Thank you Neil, however it didn't work.....ill will post below an updated version of the code....thanks

Comment: Change $('timestart').timepicker(); to $('#timestart').timepicker(); jQuery uses CSS selectors for DOM traversal. The prefix for selecting an ID in CSS is #.

Comment: That is what I first had it set to (like the datepicker) but that doesn't work either.  Thank you

Comment: Yeah but before you had a period in front of the ID. You had <input id=".timestart" /> You want <input id="timestart" /> and $("#timestart").timepicker(); The IDs have to match exactly and the ID must be prepended by '#' in the jQuery selector.

Comment: Thank you Neil, the period I had in the first post was a typo and probably a result of trying to try everything...I have since updated the code with the # instead of the . - I think the problem has something to do with mappings as per my last post, thank you

Answer (score 0):

here is the updated code, thank you

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>Home</title>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='<c:url value="/resources/css/styles.css" />' />
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='<c:url value="/resources/css/jquery-     ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css" />' />
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='<c:url     value="/resources/css/jquery.timepicker.css" />' />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script        src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>></script>
<script src='<c:url value="/resources/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js" />'></script>
<script src='<c:url value="/jquery.timepicker.min.js" />'></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.timepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.timepicker.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/base.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/base.css" />

<script>
$(function() {
  $("#dateStart").datepicker();
  $("#dateEnd").datepicker();
});

$(function() {
    $('timestart').timepicker();

  });
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id='header-container'>
<div id='header-content'>
    <a href='<c:url value="/" />'>414Cal</a>
    <div id='header-content-right'>
        <a href='<c:url value="/signout" />'>Sign Out, ${ user.email }</a>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div id='body-content'>
<h1>
    414Cal Event Creator
</h1>
<c:if test="${!empty username}">
    ${username = "User"}
</c:if>
<h3>
    ${username}
</h3>
<form action='<c:url value="/createEvent" />' method='post'>
    <p><input type='text' name='eventTitle' size='58' placeholder='Title' /></p>
    <p><input type='text' name='eventLocation' size='58' placeholder='Location' /></p>
    <p><textarea name='eventDescription' rows='5' cols='42'     placeholder='Description'></textarea></p>
    <p>Start<input type='text' name='dateStart' id='dateStart' /> <input id="timestart"     type="text" class="time" /> to <input type='text' name='dateEnd' id='dateEnd' /></p>
    <p><input type='checkbox' name='allDay'> All day</p>
    <p><input type='checkbox' name='repeat' id='repeat'> Repeat</p> 
    <p><input type='submit' /></p>

</form>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just saw this at the bottom of the console right after I load the jsp page. Thank you

WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/calendar/jquery.timepicker.min.js] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'
WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/calendar/js/jquery.timepicker.js] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'
WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/calendar/css/jquery.timepicker.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'